# Swagger/OpenAPI: How to show multiple OpenAPI specs in one SwaggerUI

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-ui

I have a bunch of backend microservices which all have their own OpenAPI spec as well as a SwaggerUI (the microservices are written in Kotlin with the Quarkus framework). Before the microservices, I had one monolith with one OpenAPI spec and one SwaggerUI.

My problem now is, that my frontend clients would need not only to know each of my microservices but they also would need to know in which microservice a certain endpoint is located.

What I want is to somehow combine all the different OpenAPI specs from all my microservices and show them in Swagger all at the same time so that my frontend users only see all the available endpoints but they don't have to have knowledge about the underlying microservices.

How would I achieve something like this? Is it even possible without somehow manually combining the OpenAPI yaml/json files?

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3372#issuecomment-333339657

Comment: check out redocly cli.. you can `join` multiple descriptions into a single one.  https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/join/